# Open predefined xlsx file in C# with ExcelDNA

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I am trying to use ExcelDNA for some routine calculations, but integrated in C#.

I am using ExcelDNA andI am unable to make my solution open a specific excel file. It either opens a new worksheet or returns an error when I write "OOPA-ExcelDNA-AddIn.xll" "Example.xlsx" in the Command line arguments option from Debug.

Could anyone please help?

Thank you!